# how to run java program outside eclipse on a server that doesn't have eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I wrote a java program that contains many classes in eclipse, it is my first time that I write a code in java and in eclipse too, now I need to run this code on a server that doesn't have eclipse.

Comment: In a server?  An application server such as tomcat or glass fish? or are you trying to create a executable jar? Your post left out a number of details.

Comment: *"plz any help? Best,"*  Advice:  1)  Spell words like 'please' correctly.  This is not a text message.  2) Ask a ***specific*** question. 3) Don't include any salutations.  They are noise.

Comment: sounds like you're either researching or doing homework. i would go into actually reading up on the link i pasted as well as reading up on simple linux commands as well as tomcat commands/configurations. you're not going to get a quick 2 second answer here because compiling a java program consisting of many, many classes isn't a simple task for somebody who has no idea what they're doing.

Answer (score 4):

[Compiling & Running a Simple Program](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html).

This is your best starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Use "File -> Export -> JAR file" wizard to create a .jar file contained your compiled classes. You can then copy this .jar file to your server and use java.exe to run it. Use "java -help" from a command line to get instructions.

Comment: this is a great quickie to people who don't want to learn about compiling complex java programs, but i think starting from my link would be a better path for him unless he's screwed for time

Comment: Depends on what one is trying to learn. Not every Java developer needs to be an expert in build systems. That's why we have an IDE like Eclipse.

Comment: I suspect your approach will not work.  Even if it does, it will result in the developer becoming a slave to the IDE.  The programmer should control the software, rather than the other way around.

Comment: Why would using the wizard not work? Knowing build systems is not a necessary component to being a Java developer. Comments about being a slave to the IDE are frankly silly. Are you a slave to Java compiler if you don't write byte code by hand? At the end of the day, its all just tools.

Answer (score -3):

**Please go through link provided by Andrew**

Eclipse is an IDE , it facilitates development but not actually required to run your code, if you want to run your java file in a server somewhere, make sure you have JRE installed in your "server" and in your Path, then run following command in your server's shell environment

```
javac filename.java
```

above command will generate a .class file in the same directory, which is actual file that can be executed using following command,

```
java filename
```

assuming your code is inside a file called filename.java

Comment: It is unnecessary to install JDK on the server; Java is portable, so it can be compiled on the user's machine and the class/jar files then run on the server.

Comment: "Eclipse is not an IDE". Typo? Because it is an IDE (amongst other things)